# Closest facilities using Pgr_Withpoint

Tags: pgrouting, closest-facility

I am trying to calculate the shortest path's distance from certain locations to their closest schools,
I used the Pgr_WithPointsCost Function to get the result from one location to its 10 closest destinations (One to Many), But I can't use the (many to many) scripts since Pgr_WithPointsCost will calculate the shortest distance between every point of the source and every target point. The problem is my data set is huge and when I launch the script it crashes.

This is the script I used to calculate the distance

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a handy function currently in pgRouting's develop branch coined [dijkstraNear](https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/blob/develop/doc/dijkstra/pgr_dijkstraNear.rst). This will help you compute many to many.

```
pgr_dijkstraNear(Edges SQL, Start vids, End vids [, directed] [, cap], [global])
RETURNS SET OF (seq, path_seq, start_vid, end_vid, node, edge, cost, agg_cost)
OR EMPTY SET
```

Comment: Do you have any ideas where to find Pgrouting 3.2, or should I wait for the official release?

Comment: @Ismail you can build the develop branch yourself, it takes a bit but you should be able to achieve with this guide https://docs.pgrouting.org/3.1/en/pgRouting-installation.html